# Selenium RemoteWebDriver - Do something if element could not be found

Tags: java, selenium

I am trying to develop a Suite of classes for testing my websites functionality every night and I do this in Chrome, Firefox, Edge and IE. Because sometimes Selenium doesn't find an element I need something that e.g. takes a screenshot of the browser before giving out an error. I don't need a function for taking a screenshot I need something that triggers when Selenium can't continue.

Best regards,
MK

Comment: please, specify in what way do you want set up trigger? And could you please provide sample of your code?

Comment: You can use `try/catch` block to catch `NoSuchElementException` and do what you want in this case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correct, you need to set up the trigger for your another system, which can react on Selenium test error.

In your test code you can use :

```
try {
// find element and test code
} catch (NoSuchElementException e) {
// set up the trigger code
}
```

To notify another system you can choose any system, which can provide notification mechanism.

In your case, you could use for example Redis with pub/sub.

So your reaction system will be a subscriber and test - provider of the event.